# How to access PgAdmin4 in web browser?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I installed the latest version of PgAdmin4 and when I opened it, it started as a separate desktop application rather than opening in my default web browser. I want to open the PostgreSQL in my web browser. How do I do that? 
Steps I tried and failed are:

1. Created a server and then a db with localhost:5432 as address
2. Tried to open the address `localhost:5432` on browser

Am I doing the right steps?

[image]

Comment: 1) pgAdmin != Postgres so `localhost:5432` is not going to work as that would likely be the address for the Postgres server not the pgAdmin one. 2) The docs show how to do a `pgAdmin` Web server install [Server deployment](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.12/server_deployment.html). 3) I'm guessing you  really don't want and that the desktop app(what you see now) is sufficient.

Comment: Are the host address and port number defined enough to connect my Django application to Postgres? I assumed if I cannot open the address in the browser then my application won't be able to connect too.

Comment: Huh? The Postgres server is not a Web server so how would it know what to do with a request from a Web browser? The protocols are completely different. Yes the host and port information is what the Django database connection needs along with the rest of the information shown here [Django Databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases)

Comment: Understood. That makes complete sense. Thanks Adrian :) If you can add it as an answer I will be able to close this question.

Comment: Nah, this was an admin question and not a code question. Probably best just to delete the question.

Comment: Got it. I'll probably leave this here if anyone else finds it useful.

Comment: You can install pgAdmin in server mode rather than desktop mode.  Check the docs for the details.

Comment: @LibinThomas I vaguely remember I asked the same question a few years  ago. Now I just use psql. Somebody told me that you can use docker to make pgadmin  as an browser TAB, rather than an Desktop. But I didn't try it. So.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the desktop version of pgAdmin 4 greater than version 5, you can  check the `PGADMIN_INT_KEY` variable in your runtime and use it to "authenticate" when you open it in a webbrowser

The steps would go:

1. Open PgAdmin 4; in my case the latest is v8
2. Open the dialog `File > Runtime > View log`
3. Copy the UUID used as `PGADMIN_INT_KEY`
4. Check the `PGADMIN_INT_PORT`; default is 5050 in v8.
5. Open your webbrowser of choice to `localhost:<PGADMIN_INT_PORT>/?key=<PGADMIN_INIT_KEY>`

End result would look like:

`127.0.0.1:5050/?key=f8ac101a-c1da-46b3-84f6-76e7f9375be3`

You can bookmark that address in your browser for however many windows you'd want to use, but that will only work on each time that you start the pgAdmin session.

Or potentially, you'd have to set it to run on server mode, but I wouldn't know the details of how to get that to work.

Comment: Thanks, please fill in this URL: 
`localhost:{PGADMIN_INT_PORT}/?key=<PGADMIN_INIT_KEY>`

Comment: In step 3, mine (version 7.8) was "PGADMIN_INT_KEY" instead of "PGADMIN_INIT_KEY"

Answer (score 1):

Open your desktop pgAdmin4, then do the following steps:

- Open `File > Runtime > View Log`
- Scroll untill the bottom then you will find the following `Application Server URL: http://127.0.0.1:{PORT_NUMBER}/?key={YOUR_KEY}`
- Copy this and open in your browser