# Is there a way to configure so that pgadmin 4 via browser can continue to work after pgadmin 4 via desktop version is closed?

Tags: database, postgresql, browser, desktop-application, pgadmin

I have successfully run pgadmin 4 via browser thanks to the answer from [Enrique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77571730/20434715). But when I closed the desktop version of pgadmin 4, then pgadmin 4 which was run via a web browser could no longer be accessed.

Is there a way to configure the desktop version of pgadmin 4 so that pgadmin 4 via web browser continues to work when the desktop version is closed?

**Searched for the answer from stackoverflow and got the answer.** (*Sorry no pictures as I don't have a reputation yet*)

Comment: no pgadmin provides the webserver, that you connect with, so no

Comment: You might be able to run pgadmin in the background without an application window though. That will depend on your operating system etc though.

Comment: oh I see, thanks guys I have gained an understanding of pgadmin and get the answer [here](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/)